# How to use resetLoadMoreRowsCache?

Tags: react-virtualized

In react virtualized, I'm trying to reset the rows if someone filters on certain critera.

I've tried calling:

Using refs

`this.infiniteLoaderRef.resetLoadMoreRowsCache();`

and the function that supposedly exists?

`InfiniteLoader.resetLoadMoreRowsCache();`

But it can't find resetLoadMoreRowsCache either way.

What's the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The refs API has changed a bit in newer releases of React. This might work for you

```js
this.infiniteLoaderRef.current.resetLoadMoreRowsCache();
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs